# .png and .eps files generated by matplotlib won't print on RHEL 5

Tags: matplotlib, png, eps, rhel5, cups

I'm using matplotlib.pyplot to plot some data, and after running plt.show() I save the image as either a PNG image or encapsulated postscript.

When I open these saved files with evince and try to print them, a job is sent to the printer but nothing is printed. The plots display on the screen with no problems.

Is there something specific I need to do in matplotlib to generate printable PNGs and EPSes? Is this a bug in matplotlib?

Comment: Usually you cannot print .eps at all (and if they are printed they are converted before that to .ps or .pdf). Regarding the PNG, I don't know what could be the issue.

Comment: Rubbis^Not correct. If you can print PostScript, then you can also print EPS. *Can* you print PostScript?!?

Comment: @pipitas: Actually, I can print after running `eps2eps` on the file. So I can print eps, just not eps not coming directly from matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps to start debugging this situation:

- (1) Stop your `cupsd` (CUPS daemon).
- (2) Change in *cupsd.conf*: `LogLevel debug` (instead of *LogLevel info*.
- (3) Delete your log file `/var/log/cups/error_log`.
- (4) Start your `cupsd` again.
- (5) Print your problem EPS.
- (6) Check your *cupsd.conf* logfile for errors.

Report the errors here. (Errors may be recognized by the prefixed `E` on each line.) Also, what is the result of the `Auto-typing` step?

Alternatively: can you provide a link to a sample of your problem EPS?